# Make another cache as default in ehcache

Tags: java, ehcache

How to make another cache declared in ehcache.xml as default than `<defaultCache/>` element.

```
<ehcache>
  <!-- <defaultCache xxxxxx /> -->
   <cache name="mynewDefault" />
</ehcache>
```

Now I would like to make the mynewDefault as default cache.  Please note defaultCache is commented.

Answer (score 0):

The defaultCache-Properties are used whenever you add a cache to the CacheManager, that was not placed in the configuration. In your case, the settings just apply to the cache named "mynewDefault". Just Change the properties of  and everything should work the way you want.